# jsp safari browser windows file download content disposition file name became -

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, safari

below code is used for the download attachment encoding chinese character for file name.

```
w_inf_src = new File(p_filepath);
   w_inf = new FileInputStream(w_inf_src);
   p_response.setContentType(w_mime+";charset=UTF-8");
   p_response.setContentLength(new Long(w_inf_src.length()).intValue());
   p_response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   p_request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

   p_response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
             "attachment;filename=\"" + (new java.net.URI(null, null, p_request, p_filename, null)).toASCIIString() + "\"");


   // Download File In Progress  
   w_outf = p_response.getOutputStream();
   w_bof = new BufferedOutputStream(w_outf);
   while ( (w_bytes_read = w_inf.read(w_buffer, 0, w_buffer.length)) != -1)
     w_bof.write(w_buffer, 0, w_bytes_read);      
   w_bof.flush();
```

I also tried the filename*=UTF-8''< encoded file name > but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using at least java 7 and Sevlet API 3.0, this is the way to go:

```
File w_inf_src = new File(p_filepath);
String encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
String w_disposition = String.format("%s;filename=\"%3$s\"; filename*=%2$s''%3$s",
    Part.ATTACHMENT,
    encoding,
    URLEncoder.encode(p_filename, encoding).replace("+", "%20"));

p_response.setContentType(w_mime);
p_response.setContentLengthLong(w_inf_src.length());
p_response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
p_response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", w_disposition);

byte[] w_buffer = new byte[p_response.getBufferSize()];
try(FileInputStream w_inf = new FileInputStream(w_inf_src);
    OutputStream w_outf = p_response.getOutputStream())
{
    int n;
    while((n = w_inf.read(w_buffer)) != -1)
    {
        w_outf.write(w_buffer, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. this is the most accurate *disposition* form you'll get, since it's *urlencoded* and *space-sanitized*.
2. it's redundant to set the encoding in both *content-type* and *content-encoding*
3. it's superfluous to set the *request* encoding: you are not reading.
4. it's redundant to use a `BufferedInputStream` because the *response* has an internal buffering
5. use your own buffer of the max available size (`respose.getBufferSize()`)
6. use `try-with-resources` where possible (if you are on Java 7+)
7. if you are on Servlet API 3.0+ you have `response.setContentLengthLong()`, they finally understood that an integer is not enough
8. alternatively use: `response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(w_inf_src.length()));`: this ensures that large lengths are not cutted to int size

Comment: hi, tried with this code but safari returns the encoded file name (%ee%...) not the literal chinese characters

Comment: Did you try other browsers? Do they return the correct filename?

Comment: other browser works fine including safari from mac, but safari from windows return encoded string still

Comment: It's probably a safari (windows) issue. You can do little, since you control the server side. One thing you could try is to change the windows OS file encoding (default for europe is CP1252 or ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8, hoping that safari will use it.

Comment: hi, not sure how to change the default file encoding in windows, but how do you do it? when I search in net, it only shows how to change it for notepad, I think we will drop windows safari support if it cannot be done. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Well, it seems its not even possible: https://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7. Maybe safari has an econding setting somewhere, anyway you can try to report a bug and hope for a patched release.